# How do I use dynamic arguments in my SpecFlow scenario background?

Tags: specflow

I have a feature that logs into a trading system and keys a number of trades. Theres a lot of reusable steps at the beginning of each trade (initial trade set up) But each trade has different arguments.

Here is an example

```
Scenario: Trade 1

Given I have selected my test data: "20003"
And I have connected to VMS with the following details:
| Field    | Value    |
| Username | user     |
| Password | password |
| Session  | myServer |

When I run the DCL command to set my privileges to full
Then I expect to see the following:
| Pass Criteria  | Timeout  |
| Privileges Set | 00:00:30 |

When I ICE to the test account: "System Test"
Then I expect to be ICED see the following:
| Pass Criteria         | Timeout    |
| "ICED to System Test" | "00:00:10" |

When I run a dcl to delete the company: "Test_Company"
Then I expect to see a confirmation that company: "Test_Company" has been deleted or doesnt exist
```

So within those steps the 2 things that could change is the "Given" argument so the test data ID and also the Test company at the end.

What I wanted was some way to run a background step so that its being able to know what parameters to enter. So if it was Trade 1 for example it would enter 20003, if it was Trade 2 enter 20004 etc.
Can I do this? I was thinking using the "Example" table that Scenario Outline uses. Or is there a better way to do this? I dont want these repeatable steps in all of my scenarios as it takes up lots of room and doesnt look too readable.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but [here is a related post from the google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specflow/6bzgl9LYOFI) which has some options for workarounds

Comment: Ah interesting. Maybe I can use the ScenarioContext to get the current scenario name and read off a table based on that then.

Answer (score 1):

So I did some searching and couldn't find a solution that didn't require a lot of coding so I made this up:

this is what the background looks like

```
Background:
Given I have selected my test data:
| Scenario          | ID    |
| DirectCredit_GBP  | 20003 |
| Cheque_GBP        | 20004 |
| ForeignCheque_GBP | 20005 |
```

And in order to find which row it should use the method behind it uses ScenarioContext. Here is the method:

```
    [Given(@"I have selected my test data:")]
    [When(@"I have selected my test data:")]
    public static void setTestDataID(Table data)
    {
        string scenario = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title;
        string testDataId = data.ReadTable("Scenario", scenario, "ID"));
        TestDriver.LoadTestData(testDataId);
    }
```

What the method does is search the table for the scenario name (using an extension method I wrote) and get the ID, once its got the ID it passes it into my TestDriver method.

It seems to work fine and keeps the test readable.